# Running an array of processes

Tags: arrays, bash

I have the following array:

```
procs=(
'one a b c'
'two d e f'
'three g h i'
)
```

I try run these processes from a loop (using echo instead of eval so I can debug):

```
for proc in ${procs[@]}
do
  echo $proc
done
```

I get:

```
one
a
b
c
two
d
e
f
three
g
h
i
```

I wanted:

```
one a b c
two d e f
three g h i
```

What went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
for proc in "${procs[@]}"
do
  echo $proc
done
```

Comment: Wait, is the same as what I tried?  I don't notice a difference.

Comment: It properly quotes the array variable.